# change progressbar and seekbar directon of jplayer to rtl instead of ltl

Tags: progress-bar, seekbar, jplayer, direction

I am using jplayer for one of the arabic site which plays arabic song. They need progress bar should go from right to left and also they should seek from right to left. I added the

```
.jp-progress
{
direction:rtl
}
```

But only progress bar is coming from right to left but seek bar is same as before. I dont know where to edit on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on seekbar function instead of

```
 x = e.pageX - offset.left
```

Replace with

```
 x = (($bar.offset().left + $bar.outerWidth())-e.pageX); // to get right offset
```

New code will be

```
seekBar: function(e) { // Handles clicks on the seekBar
 if(this.css.jq.seekBar.length) {
            // Using $(e.currentTarget) to enable multiple seek bars
 var $bar = $(e.currentTarget),
 offset = $bar.offset(),
     x = (($bar.offset().left + $bar.outerWidth())-e.pageX); // new line for rtl 
  //x = e.pageX - offset.left, // old line fro ltr
 w = $bar.width(),
 p = 100 * x / w;
     this.playHead(p);
 }
}
```

and css as you mentioned keep same

```
.jp-progress
{
direction:rtl
}
```

Comment: seekbar is seeking right  to left with above code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

only add bellow code in seekbar property of XML File.

android:rotation="180"